# Custom attributes are not reflected on the salesforce side

Tags: mobilepush, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

there was no such problem before, but after 1 month, custom attributes are not reflected on the salesforce side for newly created users. I am using version 8.0.8 of sdk

```
~!EventManager  D  (IdentityUpdate) event logged with attributes {platform=Android, registrationId=6347d320-e9fc-44f9-af09-95533eeaa36e, moduleIdentities={"push":{"profileId":"71217696","applicationId":"████████-████-████-████-████████████","installationId":"6347d320-e9fc-44f9-af09-95533eeaa36e","customProperties":{"deviceId":"6347d320-e9fc-44f9-af09-95533eeaa36e","attributes":{},"tags":["ALL","Android","DEBUG"]}}}}

~!EventManager  D  (IdentityUpdate) event logged with attributes {platform=Android, registrationId=6347d320-e9fc-44f9-af09-95533eeaa36e, moduleIdentities={"push":{"profileId":"71217696","applicationId":"████████-████-████-████-████████████","installationId":"6347d320-e9fc-44f9-af09-95533eeaa36e","customProperties":{"deviceId":"6347d320-e9fc-44f9-af09-95533eeaa36e","attributes":{"ReachByPhone":"true","Email":"cepew30079@lieboe.com","UserName":"ddeneme267","FirstName":"Deneme","Corporate":"false","ReachByEmail":"true","LastName":"Deneme","ReachBySms":"true","userid":"71217696","MobilePhone":null},"tags":["ALL","Android","DEBUG"]}}}}
```

In the logs, it seems that the data is being uploaded to the salesforce side.

The above data is for testing purposes. It doesn't matter.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem.
The problem is val attributesMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
It was because I mistyped it.

Comment: Confused. You mistyped what? That doesn't make any sense if your identity item is showing those attributes then they should have been applied.

What I don't see in your screenshot are any of those attributes. They _MUST_ be created in the MC UI and they are "set" and "cleared" by the SDK, but they cannot be "added" or "removed".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).